# Get first 4 posts from facebook fanpage without access token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can I fetch facebook fanpage posts with graph https://graph.facebook.com/ using php when I try curl on this I get blank/no-response

I like to avoid using fb token if possible otherwise would like to use latest php sdk

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just use an [App Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/) for this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/page-id/feed?access_token=APP-ID|APP-SECRET
```

...or if you only want to get the posts from the Page, without the User posts:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/page-id/posts?access_token=APP-ID|APP-SECRET
```

More information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/feed